# Relationship between integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

suppose $f(x)$ is an increasing function. $a,b$ are arbitrary constants. Is there a relation between the following three integrals:

$$ \int_0^{a+b} f(x)~dx~~~~,~~~ \int_0^a f(x)~dx~~~,~~~~\int_0^b f(x)~dx~~?$$

Can we for instance say the $$ \int_0^{a+b} f(x)~dx \gt  \int_0^a f(x)~dx~ + \int_0^b f(x)~dx~~ ?$$

What If $f(x)$ is decreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is.

$$
\int_0^{a+b} f(x)dx - \int_0^a f(x) dx
= \int_a^{a+b} f(x) dx = \int_0^b f(a+u) du
$$

Now use the fact that $f$ is increasing to get
$$
\int_0^b f(a+u) du \ge
 \int_0^b f(u) du
\\
\implies \int_0^{a+b} f(x)dx \ge 
\int_0^a f(x) dx + \int_0^b f(x) dx
$$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add some explanations?

Comment: @Joey: the first equality is the Chasles relation. The second is the change of variables $x = a+u$. The first inequality is the relation $a\ge 0 \implies f(a+u) \ge f(u) $ ($f$ is increasing) integrated (positivity of $\int$). The last thing is the different put together.

Comment: Ok. will the inequality reverse if $f$ was decreasing?

Comment: indeed! because it is the only inequality here, reversed in case of a decreasing function.